# SQL advanced sorting

Tags: sql

I'm facing a problem with sorting groups of data in a very old (13 years or so) SQL database program. The data looks like this:

```
    Entry     Batch  Time
    1         1      7-1-2013 13:35
    2         1      3-3-2014  7:48
    3         1      1-2-2014 18:49
    4         2      3-1-2011 13:23
    5         2      5-3-2014 20:48
    6         2      7-2-2014  3:11
    7         3      2-3-2012 15:09
    8         3      5-3-2014 10:37
    9         3      6-2-2014  7:16
```

I want to sort the entries by grouping those from the same batches together, and then sort them based on the lowest time entry in those groups. In this example, the group order would be 2-3-1 and the entry order would be `4-6-5-9-7-8-1-3-2`.

Is there any easy way to do this? I tried working with order by (select blah), but no success so far. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The program is called QRDesign Barcovision. Just checked, it has a 2009 update, maybe it's not so bad.. not sure what to answer on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading correctly, you want to sort on groups by the oldest date in the group first and then by time.

If this were oracle or sql server, you could use analytics for this:

```
select Entry, 
       Batch, 
       Time
from ( select Entry, 
              Batch, 
              Time, 
              MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Batch) AS MinTime
       from MyTable ) MyTable2
order by MinTime, Time
```

If you do not have a database that supports this, you could try the following:

```
select MyTable.Entry, 
       MyTable.Batch, 
       MyTable.Time
from MyTable
join ( select Batch, MIN(Time) AS MinTime
       from MyTable ) MyTable2 on MyTable.Batch = MyTable2.Batch
order by MyTable2.MinTime, MyTable.Time
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that he wants to order the batches in a non-natural way (i.e. not ascending nor descending)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar If you take the lowest Time for every Batch and order on that, the Batch order is 2-3-1

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. Well, seems that then my answer is invalid, too ;-)